# BulkCreate with a 1 to 1 relationship using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, data-modeling

**Description:**

I have a table `ProductGroupItems` that is in a 1 to 1 relationship with `BonusGroupItems` and `ThresholdGroupItems`. Sometimes a `ProductGroupItem` is a bonus item other times its a threshold item. I chose this so that `ProductGroupItems` wouldn't have any columns that were null.

**Question:**

How do I insert multiple `ProductGroupItems` and its corresponding 1 to 1 table (`Threshold` or `Bonus`) using `Sequelize.bulkCreate`?

**What I have tried:**

1. Looping through values and making a separate `create()` each time. This does work but fires a query for EACH record, obviously.
2. `models.ProductGroupItems.bulkCreate(productItems, { return: true })` then doing something fancy with the values that come back. This was too confusing and I ended up not being able to figure it out.

Any help?

Comment: [bulkCreate](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5498) doesnt support it as of now fwir
You could use build with include and save. That would create the record with it's association. But then again it's multiple queries fired